# CSS breaks on refresh in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a nav bar for my website that when initially loaded in chrome looks like this:

```
|      |      |           |
| Home | News | Solutions | etc...
|      |      |           |
```

Now for some reason if I load this page and then proceed to refresh the page in chrome (without changing anything) it ends up breaking and looking like this:

```
|   |   |   |   |
|  HomeNewsSoultionEtc...
|   |   |   |   |
```

The links which are contained using the `< a >` attribute no longer expand the `< li >` they are contained in. I'm assuming its a calculations error on chrome's part because I've tested this in firefox, IE, and safari and it works perfectly.

My code is below:

```
<div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-4 logo_box">

                <p><a href="..."><img src="..."></a></p>

            </div>

            <div class="col-md-8 nav_box">

                <ul>

                    <li onclick="location.href='...';" class="mainlink"><a class="ml_text" href="...">Home</a></li>
                    <li onclick="location.href='...';" class="mainlink"><a class="ml_text" href="...">News</a></li>
                    <!-- etc... -->

               </ul>

           </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.nav_box
{
    height: auto;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0%;
    margin-top: auto;
    float: right;
}

.nav_box li
{
    width: auto;
}

.nav_box ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.mainlink:hover
{
    background-color: #b3babf;
}
```

Comment: Please post your HTML and css so we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache? In your first load, it may have used a cached CSS. When you hit ctrl+R, or the refresh button, the browser may ask for a fresh copy of the full page.

Comment: Clearing the cache didn't help.

Comment: You need to link to your website, or even better, create a reproduction of your problem so we can analyze it.

Answer (score 0):

Clear your Browsing data. You're fighting between cached css and your own.